# Update or Save if not exists

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've got a use case where I want to save a document if it doesn't exist, and if it does exist, I want to just update it. I'd be fine if it re-saved the entire document, so I was trying to just simply use save(), but I was getting `MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index` errors when I was re-saving an already existing document.

The obvious solution is to have 2 code paths where if the document exists, then to update the field, otherwise save, but I was just wondering if there was a more elegant solution than this.

**Side question:** Is the best way to tell if a document already exists to see if _id is is set?

Comment: Save only works on the `_id` field, clearly your unique key is probably something else as such you should probably be using upsert instead.

Comment: @Sammaye upsert will insert a document that doesn't exist?

Comment: Yeah it will, so you call an update with a upsert option